# Navigation Mesh

Tags: game-engine

The game I'm working on involves the enemy following the player through rooms; however, when I add a Navigational Mesh for the enemy, the mesh doesn't pass through the rooms, so the enemy is stuck inside one room. Is there a way to make the Navigational Mesh large enough for the enemy to transition from one room to the other?
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUfxj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the solution to your problem!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NYNS.png